# Stopping T-SQL converting Hex to ASCII

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, hex, ascii

I'm trying to get a trimmed hex value from an INT.
I am currently converting an INT to Hex with no troubles using;

```
convert(varbinary(1),43) --This is creating a 0x2B result
```

I want to only show the value 2B
When I do any sort of conversion to VARCHAR(), by cast or even by right() the hex is converted to the ASCII character and then I can't do anything with it.

Does anyone know the way of preserving the HEX value while removing the leading 0x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is in the range 0 to 255 you can use brute force:

```
-- One value.
declare @VB as VarBinary(1) = 43;
select @VB as [VarBinary], Substring( '0123456789ABCDEF', Ascii( @VB ) / 16 + 1, 1 ) + Substring( '0123456789ABCDEF', Ascii( @VB ) & 15 + 1, 1 ) as [Hex];

-- Test the range 0 to 255.
with Numbers as (
  select 0 as Number
  union all
  select Number + 1
    from Numbers
    where Number < 255 ),
  NumbersWithVarBinary as (
    select Number, Cast( Number as VarBinary(1) ) as VB
      from Numbers )
  select VB as [VarBinary], Substring( '0123456789ABCDEF', Ascii( VB ) / 16 + 1, 1 ) + Substring( '0123456789ABCDEF', Ascii( VB ) & 15 + 1, 1 ) as [Hex]
    from NumbersWithVarBinary
    option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

Extending the range is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

You can use the inbuilt function like this:

```
select 
RIGHT(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(convert(varbinary(1),43)),LEN(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(convert(varbinary(1),43)))-CHARINDEX('x',sys.fn_varbintohexstr(convert(varbinary(1),43))))
```

Comment: That you, but has it the same problem, the conversion to VARCHAR for the right function converts the HEX to ASCII equivalent as a preprocess

Comment: Works, I was just trying to avoid the undocumented sys function, but seems that isn't the case.